# Set Django's FileField to an existing file

Tags: python, django, file

I have an existing file on disk (say /folder/file.txt) and a FileField model field in Django.

When I do

```
instance.field = File(file('/folder/file.txt'))
instance.save()
```

it re-saves the file as `file_1.txt` (the next time it's `_2`, etc.).

I understand why, but I don't want this behavior - I know the file I want the field to be associated with is really there waiting for me, and I just want Django to point to it.

How?

Comment: Not sure you can get what you want without modifying Django or subclassing `FileField`. Whenever a `FileField` is saved, a new copy of the file is created. It would be fairly straightforward to add an option to avoid this.

Comment: well yes, looks like I have to subclass and add a param. I don't wnat to create extra tables for this simple task

Comment: Put the file in a different location, create your field with this path, save it and then you have the file in the upload_to destination.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to do this permanently, you need to create your own FileStorage class

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

class MyFileStorage(FileSystemStorage):

    # This method is actually defined in Storage
    def get_available_name(self, name):
        if self.exists(name):
            os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, name))
        return name # simply returns the name passed
```

Now in your model, you use your modified MyFileStorage

```
from mystuff.customs import MyFileStorage

mfs = MyFileStorage()

class SomeModel(model.Model):
   my_file = model.FileField(storage=mfs)
```

Comment: oh, looks promising. cuase the FileField's code is kinda non-intuitive

Comment: but... is it possible to change storage on a per-request basis, like: instance.field.storage = mfs; instance.field.save(name, file); but not doing it in a different branch of my code

Comment: No, since the storage engine is tied to the model. You can avoid all this by simply storing your file path in either a `FilePathField` or simply as plain text.

Comment: You can't just return a name. You need to remove existing file first.

Comment: This solution is only seemingly correct as this solution actually removes the file already present and creates a new one with the same name. In the end, it does NOT "point to it" as the author wrote. Imagine a situation where the user wants to point to a large file but actually ends up removing it and uploading it from scratch.

Answer (score 158):

just set `instance.field.name` to the path of your file

e.g.

```
class Document(models.Model):
    file = FileField(upload_to=get_document_path)
    description = CharField(max_length=100)


doc = Document()
doc.file.name = 'path/to/file'  # must be relative to MEDIA_ROOT
doc.file
<FieldFile: path/to/file>
```

Comment: The relative path from your `MEDIA_ROOT`, that is.

Comment: In this example, I think you can also just do `doc.file = 'path/to/file'`

Answer (score 24):

try this ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/#django.core.files.File.name)):

```
instance.field.name = <PATH RELATIVE TO MEDIA_ROOT> 
instance.save()
```

Answer (score 5):

It's right to write own storage class. However `get_available_name` is not the right method to override.

`get_available_name` is called when Django sees a file with same name and tries to get a new available file name. It's not the method that causes the rename. the method caused that is `_save`. Comments in `_save` is pretty good and you can easily find it opens file for writing with flag `os.O_EXCL` which will throw an OSError if same file name already exists. Django catches this Error then calls `get_available_name` to get a new name.

So I think the correct way is to override `_save` and call os.open() without flag `os.O_EXCL`. The modification is quite simple however the method is a little be long so I don't paste it here. Tell me if you need more help :)

Comment: it's 50 lines of code that you have to copy, which is pretty bad. Overriding get_available_name seems is more isolated, shorter, and much more safer for, say, upgrading to the newer versions of Django in future

Comment: The problem of *only* overriding `get_available_name` is when you upload a file with same name, the server will get into an endless loop. Since `_save` checks the file name and decides to get a new one however `get_available_name` still returns the duplicate one. So you need to override both.

Comment: Oops, we're having this discussion in two questions, but only now I noticed that they are slightly different) So I'm right in that question, and you are in this)

Answer (score 3):

The answers work fine if you are using the app's filesystem to store your files. But, If your are using boto3 and uploading to sth like **AWS S3** and maybe you want to set a file already **existing in an S3 bucket** to your model's FileField then, this is what you need.

We have a simple model class with a filefield:

```py
class Image(models.Model):
    
    img = models.FileField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images')

    date_added = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(editable=True)
```

```py
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import boto3
    
s3 = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=os.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"),
    aws_secret_access_key=os.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
)

s3_key = S3_DIR + '/' + filename
bucket_name = os.getenv("AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME")

try:
    s3.upload_file(local_file_path, bucket_name, s3_key)
    # we want to store it to our db model called **Image** after s3 upload is complete so,
    image_data = Image()
    image_data.img.name = s3_key # this does it !!
    image_data.owner = get_user_model().objects.get(id=owner_id)
    image_data.save()
except ClientError as e:
    print(f"failed uploading to s3 {e}")
```

Setting the **S3 KEY** into the **name** field of the **FileField** does the trick. As much i have tested everything related works as expected e.g previewing the image file in django admin. fetching the images from db appends the root s3 bucket prefix (or, the cloudfront cdn prefix) to the s3 keys of the files too. Ofcourse, its given that, i already had a working setup of the django settings.py for boto and s3.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem! then I realize that my Models were causing that. example I hade my models like this:

```
class Tile(models.Model):
  image = models.ImageField()
```

Then, I wanted to have more the one tile referencing the same file in the disk! The way that I found to solve that was change my Model structure to this:

```
class Tile(models.Model):
  image = models.ForeignKey(TileImage)

class TileImage(models.Model):
  image = models.ImageField()
```

Which after I realize that make more sense, because if I want the same file being saved more then one in my DB I have to create another table for it!

I guess you can solve your problem like that too, just hoping that you can change the models!

**EDIT**

Also I guess you can use a different storage, like this for instance: SymlinkOrCopyStorage

http://code.welldev.org/django-storages/src/11bef0c2a410/storages/backends/symlinkorcopy.py

Comment: makes sense in your case, not in mine. I don't want it to be referenced multiple times. I create an object referencing a file, then I realize there're errors in other attrs, and I reopen the creation form. On its resubmission I don't want to loose the file which is already saved on the disk

Comment: so I guess you can use my approach! because you will have a table FormFile which will hold the file only then you have ! then in your Form table you`ll have an FK for that file! so You can change/create new forms for the same file! (btw I am changing the order of the FK in my main example)

Comment: If you want to post your domain(models) in your post ! i can have a better ideia too!

Comment: the domain actually doesn't matter - I have a model with a photo associated with it, and I have custom editing screen. once uploaded I want the photo to remain on server, but I don't actually like spawning a separate model, table and FK lookup just because the're looks to be a framework limitation

Comment: The limitation here I guess is because of when you save a FileField in django, always it passes through Django Storages! so it wont make sense you just force a file path! also how Django should know that the file already exist in the path? another approach that you can use is using the FilePathField instead! so you can just set path in your DB and make the lookup the way you think is best!

Comment: I guess I found a django-storage that could help you aim what you want, check it your my post EDIT!

Comment: thanks for your effort, but it looks really complicating things. I should probably just subclass the ImageField (the one I actually use) and give it an option to force it not to re-save the file

Comment: The URL pointing to `SymLinkOrCopy` is broken. Use [this](https://github.com/e-loue/django-storages/blob/master/storages/backends/symlinkorcopy.py) instead. Also, note that there are two `django-storages` repositories on github: 1. [jschneier/django-storages](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages), 2. [e-loue/django-storages](https://github.com/e-loue/django-storages)

Answer (score 1):

You should define your own storage, inherit it from FileSystemStorage, and override `OS_OPEN_FLAGS` class attribute and `get_available_name()` method:

**Django Version:** 3.1

**Project/core/files/storages/backends/local.py**

```py
import os

from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage


class OverwriteStorage(FileSystemStorage):
    """
    FileSystemStorage subclass that allows overwrite the already existing
    files.
    
    Be careful using this class, as user-uploaded files will overwrite
    already existing files.
    """

    # The combination that don't makes os.open() raise OSError if the
    # file already exists before it's opened.
    OS_OPEN_FLAGS = os.O_WRONLY | os.O_TRUNC | os.O_CREAT | getattr(os, 'O_BINARY', 0)

    def get_available_name(self, name, max_length=None):
        """
        This method will be called before starting the save process.
        """
        return name
```

In your model, use your custom OverwriteStorage

**myapp/models.py**

```py
from django.db import models

from core.files.storages.backends.local import OverwriteStorage


class MyModel(models.Model):
   my_file = models.FileField(storage=OverwriteStorage())
```