# Overriding Django Save and returning id if exists

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django_rest framework to upload files to my site. However, often I am uploading the same file, so I wish to avoid uploading the same file multiple times.

To overcome saving multiple copies of the same file, I have overwritten the save model to upload a file and delete the file if it already exists. This works although I feel it is alot of not needed uploading. However, I can't get the existing id to be returned from my serialiser to not do this. is there a better solution to this?

Model.py

```
    class IMAGES(models.Model):



        IMAGE = models.FileField(max_length=150,upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')

        def __unicode__(self):
            return str(self.id)



        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

            imstring="documents/" + datetime.now().strftime('%Y') + "/" + datetime.now().strftime('%m')  + "/" + datetime.now().strftime('%d') + "/" + str(self.IMAGE)

            try:
                this = IMAGES.objects.filter(IMAGE=imstring)[0] # This sees if the filename is already in the database.

                if this.IMAGE: # if it is,
                    # delete the file and replace it.
                    os.remove(this.IMAGE.path) 
            except IndexError:
                pass

            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                pass

            super(IMAGES, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

serializer.py

```
class IMAGESEntrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model =  IMAGES
        fields = (
            'id', 'IMAGE')

    def create(self, validated_data):


        result, other =  IMAGES.objects.get_or_create(**validated_data)

        return result

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Update and return an existing `Snippet` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        instance.NAME = validated_data.get('NAME', instance.title)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

views.py

```
class IMAGESADD(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                  mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                  generics.GenericAPIView):

    queryset = IMAGES.objects.all()
    serializer_class = IMAGESEntrySerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Hi

Has anyone got any ideas on this? Sorry for being rude to bump this up. This is just frustrating me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manged to fix this by altering this post 
[Django uploads: Discard uploaded duplicates, use existing file (md5 based check)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885201/django-uploads-discard-uploaded-duplicates-use-existing-file-md5-based-check)

Returning the name returned the id as well.