# Preventing a file upload completely if file already exists in Django

Tags: python, django, file-upload

I'm trying to make it so that when someone tries to upload a file that has already been uploaded before with a model form, the form will prevent it from submitting. Here is the relevant code:

models.py

```
class File(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
```

forms.py

```
class FileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    file = forms.FileField()

    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = ('file',)
```

views.py

```
def file_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('list_files')
        else:
            logger.error(form.errors)
    else:
        form = FileForm()

    return render(request, 'files/file_upload.html', {'form': form})
```

Let's say someone uploaded a file called document_1.xlsx. The way this code is now, if someone tries to upload another file called document_1.xlsx, it will upload it and add some weird suffix to it before the dot. I don't want that. I want the form to not allow anyone upload a file that already exists period, without breaking the code. Apparently adding 'unique=True' to the file field in the model doesn't work. I've seen so many questions that ask how to rename a file if it already exists, but I don't want that. I want to stop it completely if that file name already exists. Thanks.

EDIT:I don't believe this is a duplicate of another question. That question asks how to overwrite a file with the same name. This question is asking how to prevent a file with the same name from uploading.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent Django from changing file name when a file with that name already exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214904/how-to-prevent-django-from-changing-file-name-when-a-file-with-that-name-already)

Comment: Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the default clean method for your form to add the logic of checking if file exists before saving.

Try the below in your FileForm class:

```
import os
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def clean(self):
    file_path = "your folder/" + self.cleaned_data.get('file')
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        raise ValidationError('File already exists') 
    return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: Which module is it supposed to go in? Are you saying that it should go in forms.py within the FileForm class? Should it go before or after the class Meta?

Comment: Yes, in your forms.py, after class Meta.

Comment: Apparently adding that gave me this error when I try to upload a file: Can't convert 'InMemoryUploadedFile' object to str implicitly

Comment: You just need to str(self.cleaned_data.get('file')) and it will work :)

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this on the clean method of your form. Just check on it whether there is a form with that name. If there is one, Raise a validation error. Something like: (I'm not 100% that this would work. But the solution is down this lines)

```
def clean_file(self):
    file = self.cleaned_data['file']
    if FileModel.objects.filter(file__name=file.name).exist():
        raise ValidationError('There is already a file with that name on our system')
```