# How to save a **python-doc** object to a **DRF** model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-docx

I have a **Django Rest Framework** view that generates **python-docx** objects, and I want to save such files in a model. I read in the documentation of **python-docx** that you can specify a "file-like" object to save the object, but I don't understand what it means.

This is my view:

```
class RoomingWordView(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ... some code
        documents_to_return = self.get_hotel_document(start_date, end_date, confirmed, hotel, bookings)
        return Response(documents_to_return)

    def get_hotel_document(self, start_date, end_date, confirmed, hotel, bookings):
        from django.core.files import File
        from docx import Document
        from docx.shared import Inches, Pt

        document = Document()

        section = document.sections[-1]
        section.left_margin = Inches(0.5)
        section.right_margin = Inches(0.5)

        style = document.styles['Normal']
        font = style.font
        font.name ='Arial'
        font.size = Pt(10)

        document.add_heading("MY COMPANY")
        if confirmed:
            document.add_paragraph("ROOMING LIST DEL 01-12-2018 AL 31-01-2019 INCLUYE RESERVAS CONFIRMADAS")
        else:
            document.add_paragraph("ROOMING LIST DEL 01-12-2018 AL 31-01-2019")
        document.add_paragraph("Hotel: {}".format(hotel))

        table = document.add_table(rows=len(bookings), cols=10)
        hdr_cells = table.rows[0].cells
        hdr_cells[0].text = 'Booking'
        hdr_cells[1].text = 'Reservado a'
        hdr_cells[2].text = '# Pax'
        hdr_cells[3].text = 'Agencia'
        hdr_cells[4].text = 'Habs'
        hdr_cells[5].text = 'Hab./Plan'
        hdr_cells[6].text = 'Entrada'
        hdr_cells[7].text = 'Salida'
        hdr_cells[8].text = 'Confirmación'
        hdr_cells[9].text = 'Producción'

        for cell in table.rows[0].cells:
            paragraphs = cell.paragraphs
            for paragraph in paragraphs:
                for run in paragraph.runs:
                    run.underline = True

        for booking in bookings['bookings']:
            row_cells = table.add_row().cells
            row_cells[0].text = booking['booking']
            row_cells[1].text = "\n".join(booking['people'])
            row_cells[2].text = booking['pax']
            row_cells[3].text = booking['agency']
            row_cells[4].text = booking['rooms']
            row_cells[5].text = "{}\n{}".format(booking['room_type'], booking['plan_type'])
            row_cells[6].text = booking['check_in']
            row_cells[7].text = booking['check_out']
            row_cells[8].text = booking['confirmation']
            row_cells[9].text = str(booking['production'])

        for row in table.rows:
            for cell in row.cells:
                paragraphs = cell.paragraphs
                for paragraph in paragraphs:
                    for run in paragraph.runs:
                        font = run.font
                        font.size = Pt(8)

        file_object = "rooming_reports/Rooming {} {}-{}.docx".format(hotel, start_date, end_date)
        document.save(file_object)

        return file_object
```

I want the view to save the resulting **document** object in a model called `RoomingWordDocument`, instead of saving it as a file, but I don't know how to assign `document` variable to `RoomingWordDocument.file` field.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a model as

```
class RoomingWordDocument(models.Model):
    doc = models.FileField(null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Then try this snippet

```
class RoomingWordView(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    # your list method
    # return Response(documents_to_return)

    def get_hotel_document(self, start_date, end_date, confirmed, hotel, bookings):
        # your code
        # ......

        file_object = "rooming_reports/Rooming {} {}-{}.docx".format(hotel, start_date, end_date)
        document.save(file_object)

        # here is the new snippet
        # found a simple way now
        model_object = RoomingWordDocument.objects.create(name="somename")
        model_object.doc.name = file_object
        model_object.save() # this is importent

        try:
            from StringIO import StringIO
        except ImportError:
            from io import StringIO
        from django.core.files import File

        fp = open(file_object, 'rb')
        model_object = RoomingWordDocument.objects.create(name="somename")
        model_object.doc.save(file_object, File(fp))

        return Response("some response")
```

---

**Reference**
1. [**`StringIo`** in Python2.X and 3.X](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18284900/8283848)
2. [How to create a file and save it to a model's FileField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514964/django-how-to-create-a-file-and-save-it-to-a-models-filefield)
3. [Set Django's FileField to an existing file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10906037/8283848)

Comment: Great @JPG, thanks. I only have one question, will I end having two files in the server?

Comment: unfortunately, there will be two files :(

Comment: @HugoLuisVillalobosCanto Now I've updated the answer (check the snippet). Now, it wont create a new copy of the existing file

Comment: Check **Reference 3**  for more details